# android where clause query not working

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

```
String name="xyz";    
String sql="select * from "+table_name+" where person_name='"+name+"'";
```

Above query is working fine. but if I replace person_name with any other column name like person_item or person_trip, no results are shown and there is no error.

```
String sql="select * from "+table_name+" where person_item='"+name+"'";
```

This query doesn't work.
What can be the possible error? I have been trying to get this work for last 7 days. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps there is simply no data that matches.  If you don't have sample data in the question, that is the obvious conclusion.

Comment: Export the Data From the device and download Sqlite manager For Mozilla and open the database and check really the coloumn and data are present or no

Comment: sample data is present. select * query works perfectly fine.

Comment: @DeadlyDroid thankyou very much. when i saw the database in mozilla, i found the mistake. i was filling crossed entries in two columns.

Comment: @RonnWilder keep Going

Answer (score 0):

You could try this - using a cursor

Where myDB is an instance of SQLiteDatabase...

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_name , null);

int ITEM_COLUMN = c.getColumnIndex("person_item");

myDB.execSQL("SELECT * FROM "+table_name+" WHERE "+c.getColumnName(ITEM_COLUMN)+" = "+name+";");
```

You could read more about cursors and their interaction with databases here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html